# Why only some of my SVG are beeing cutoff? Code or SVG error?

Tags: wordpress, svg

Some of our SVG's are beeing cutoff and only a part of one path is seen.
I've checked every div/path & parent element code, but cant find a solution. All elements should share the same code.

The SVG in question: https://webshop.positioning-marketing.at/unternehmen/ (second one on the bottom).

Can someone check it and give me a hint where the problem may be, because I feel kind of lost by now.

Answer (score 0):

In your second **SVG** element (with text 'Ritati quam' under), remove **width** and **height** attributes (width="184.69" height="190.03") and keep **viewBox** only.
It should work.

```css
.elementor-section.elementor-section-boxed > .elementor-container {
    max-width: 1090px;
}
.elementor-section.elementor-section-boxed>.elementor-container {
    max-width: 1140px;
}
.elementor-section .elementor-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.elementor *, .elementor :after, .elementor :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
.elementor {
    -webkit-hyphens: manual;
    -ms-hyphens: manual;
    hyphens: manual;
}
.elementor-kit-8 {
    --e-global-color-primary: #6EC1E4;
    --e-global-color-secondary: #54595F;
    --e-global-color-text: #7A7A7A;
    --e-global-color-accent: #61CE70;
    --e-global-typography-primary-font-weight: 600;
    --e-global-typography-secondary-font-weight: 400;
    --e-global-typography-text-font-weight: 400;
    --e-global-typography-accent-font-weight: 500;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-be640c2" data-id="be640c2" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <section data-particle_enable="false" data-particle-mobile-disabled="false" class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-668fa90 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="668fa90" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-wider">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-25 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-fa1ae84" data-id="fa1ae84" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-f1fdfed elementor-view-default elementor-position-top elementor-vertical-align-top elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon-box" data-id="f1fdfed" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon-box.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-box-wrapper">
                        <div class="elementor-icon-box-icon">
                <span class="elementor-icon elementor-animation-">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 138.5 122.5" ><metadata></metadata><defs id="defs74"></defs>
<g id="g69">
    <defs id="defs60">
        <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="7.4" y="5.8" width="124.6" height="111.8"></rect>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" id="use62"></use>
    </clipPath>
    
        <path style="color:#000000;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:medium;line-height:normal;font-family:sans-serif;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-position:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-alternates:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;font-variation-settings:normal;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;letter-spacing:normal;word-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;writing-mode:lr-tb;direction:ltr;text-orientation:mixed;dominant-baseline:auto;baseline-shift:baseline;text-anchor:start;white-space:normal;shape-padding:0;shape-margin:0;inline-size:0;clip-rule:nonzero;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;color-interpolation:sRGB;color-interpolation-filters:linearRGB;solid-color:#000000;solid-opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;color-rendering:auto;image-rendering:auto;shape-rendering:auto;text-rendering:auto;enable-background:accumulate;stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;opacity:1" d="M 40 5.8007812 C 21.847239 5.8007812 7.4003906 22.469892 7.4003906 42.5 C 7.4003906 51.090244 9.1172025 59.466889 14.949219 66.083984 C 16.507178 67.851669 20.340567 71.608149 25.527344 76.621094 C 30.71412 81.634038 37.131082 87.754707 43.384766 93.689453 C 55.892133 105.55894 67.746094 116.6875 67.746094 116.6875 A 3.0003 3.0003 0 0 0 71.849609 116.69141 C 71.849609 116.69141 83.402794 105.88741 95.623047 94.330078 C 101.73317 88.551412 108.01077 82.583321 113.09961 77.677734 C 118.18845 72.772148 121.97467 69.067217 123.54883 67.285156 C 129.4149 60.644321 132.09961 51.868182 132.09961 42.5 C 132.09961 22.469892 117.64185 5.8007812 99.400391 5.8007812 C 86.062043 5.8007812 74.812796 14.761322 69.693359 27.421875 C 64.554127 14.757403 53.275339 5.8007813 40 5.8007812 z M 40 11.800781 C 54.447239 11.800781 66.699219 25.332764 66.699219 42.599609 A 3.0003 3.0003 0 0 0 72.699219 42.599609 C 72.699219 25.322069 84.841854 11.800781 99.400391 11.800781 C 113.95893 11.800781 126.09961 25.330108 126.09961 42.5 C 126.09961 50.731818 123.78471 57.955288 119.05078 63.314453 C 117.97494 64.532392 113.99983 68.477461 108.93555 73.359375 C 103.87126 78.241289 97.604327 84.199369 91.501953 89.970703 C 80.351818 100.51597 71.553286 108.74296 69.804688 110.37891 C 68.051105 108.73178 58.956757 100.19357 47.515625 89.335938 C 41.269309 83.408183 34.860489 77.296821 29.697266 72.306641 C 24.534042 67.31646 20.493213 63.299503 19.451172 62.117188 C 14.883188 56.934283 13.400391 50.309756 13.400391 42.5 C 13.400391 25.330108 25.552761 11.800781 40 11.800781 z " id="path65"></path>
    
        <path style="color:#000000;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:medium;line-height:normal;font-family:sans-serif;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-position:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-alternates:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;font-variation-settings:normal;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;letter-spacing:normal;word-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;writing-mode:lr-tb;direction:ltr;text-orientation:mixed;dominant-baseline:auto;baseline-shift:baseline;text-anchor:start;white-space:normal;shape-padding:0;shape-margin:0;inline-size:0;clip-rule:nonzero;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;color-interpolation:sRGB;color-interpolation-filters:linearRGB;solid-color:#000000;solid-opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;color-rendering:auto;image-rendering:auto;shape-rendering:auto;text-rendering:auto;enable-background:accumulate;stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;opacity:1" d="M 95.199219 20.699219 A 3 3 0 0 0 92.199219 23.699219 A 3 3 0 0 0 95.199219 26.699219 C 104.56286 26.699219 112.19922 34.335582 112.19922 43.699219 A 3 3 0 0 0 115.19922 46.699219 A 3 3 0 0 0 118.19922 43.699219 C 118.19922 31.062855 107.83558 20.699219 95.199219 20.699219 z " id="path67"></path>
</g>
</svg>              </span>
            </div>
                        <div class="elementor-icon-box-content">
                <h3 class="elementor-icon-box-title">
                    <span>COMPANY</span>
                </h3>
                                <p class="elementor-icon-box-description">Ces explaboreped que</p>
                            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-25 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-251a685" data-id="251a685" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-ec53447 elementor-view-default elementor-position-top elementor-vertical-align-top elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon-box" data-id="ec53447" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon-box.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-box-wrapper">
                        <div class="elementor-icon-box-icon">
                <span class="elementor-icon elementor-animation-">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"  viewBox="0 0 184.69 190.03" xml:space="preserve"><metadata></metadata><defs><clipPath id="clipPath20"><path d="m54.055 75.73h1260v1280.7h-1260z"></path></clipPath></defs><g transform="matrix(1.3333 0 0 -1.3333 0 190.03)"><g transform="scale(.1)"><g clip-path="url(#clipPath20)" fill="#7fb300"><path d="m741.64 371.58c-0.247 5.93-2.969 11.5-7.512 15.359l-40.391 34.168c66.301 0.102 132.45 25.301 182.09 74.93 4.211 4.219 6.457 9.988 6.211 15.938-0.242 5.937-2.969 11.503-7.508 15.363l-60.539 51.211c61.75 3.972 123.83 30.781 172.97 79.922 4.238 4.226 6.484 10.066 6.203 16.05-0.273 5.981-3.078 11.582-7.695 15.395l-43.321 35.789c-4.199 3.457-8.605 6.523-12.968 9.648 52.625 10.997 105.86 39.407 150.42 83.965 4.3 4.297 6.56 10.227 6.2 16.289-0.36 6.067-3.29 11.68-8.05 15.442l-30.33 23.965c-21.54 17-46.49 28.074-73.248 33.699 13.215 8.601 26.098 18.535 37.958 30.41 74.27 74.255 79.61 186.58 79.8 191.32 0.24 5.93-2 11.7-6.21 15.9-4.2 4.2-9.78 6.36-15.91 6.22-4.74-0.19-117.06-5.54-191.32-79.79-11.855-11.87-21.797-24.75-30.398-37.97-5.617 26.77-16.711 51.72-33.711 73.24l-23.945 30.34c-3.77 4.76-9.395 7.7-15.45 8.05-6.035 0.32-12.004-1.89-16.289-6.19-44.59-44.6-72.91-97.87-83.906-150.55-3.137 4.414-6.23 8.848-9.719 13.089l-35.789 43.33c-3.82 4.62-9.406 7.4-15.39 7.69-6.028 0.24-11.817-1.98-16.047-6.21-49.11-49.117-76.043-111.14-80.02-172.85l-51.121 60.422c-3.84 4.539-9.414 7.274-15.351 7.512-6.125 0.32-11.719-2.004-15.93-6.211-49.715-49.719-74.668-115.98-74.695-182.39l-34.426 40.676c-3.836 4.551-9.414 7.285-15.352 7.52-6.133 0.324-11.726-2.004-15.926-6.204-94.043-94.05-100.41-247.26-14.511-348.79l2.519-2.976c-26.75-27.582-121.25-127.69-216.31-260.78-21.836-30.59-14.727-73.239 15.859-95.09 11.641-8.3086 25.332-12.699 39.578-12.699 21.992 0 42.746 10.66 55.52 28.54 87.488 122.49 175.3 216.12 201.44 243.23l7.539-6.359c47.82-40.461 107.09-60.45 166.27-60.45 66.433 0 132.75 25.207 182.5 74.95 4.207 4.218 6.453 9.988 6.211 15.941m-156.69 321.25 20.078-24.324c0.43-0.52 0.949-0.918 1.418-1.387 0.477-0.488 0.899-1.027 1.446-1.469l24.316-20.086c-20.539-1.621-40.832-5.976-60.344-13.078 7.09 19.516 11.465 39.785 13.086 60.344m129.12 124.84 17.403-22.063c0.05-0.066 0.128-0.105 0.175-0.164 0.442-0.547 0.977-1.008 1.465-1.515 0.578-0.563 1.106-1.172 1.731-1.688 0.066-0.039 0.097-0.098 0.156-0.137l22.059-17.422c-20.282-3.125-40.352-8.808-59.883-16.875 8.066 19.524 13.761 39.602 16.894 59.864m-245.65-286.13c0.391-0.449 0.859-0.813 1.277-1.223 0.41-0.418 0.762-0.886 1.211-1.269l40.676-34.422c-32.629-8e-3 -65.148-6.074-95.742-18.164 12.09 30.617 18.133 63.133 18.144 95.761zm86.113-17.52-38.488 32.578 3.937 3.926c67.149 67.117 176.52 71.692 249.02 10.352l59.414-50.285c-79.035-63.336-195.08-63.258-273.89 3.429m123.77 148.65-24.414 20.168c79.14 65.269 187.82 70.625 261.16 10.054l24.414-20.164c-79.141-65.293-187.82-70.636-261.16-10.058m353.5 170.44c-77.304-65.176-179.11-79.734-240.09-31.562h-8e-3l-10.762 8.488c77.313 65.168 179.1 79.727 240.1 31.582zm-123.23 209.56c43.086 43.07 104 58.76 137.84 64.37-5.6-33.85-21.29-94.78-64.355-137.85-43.078-43.066-104-58.762-137.84-64.355 5.598 33.847 21.301 94.765 64.355 137.83m-136.07 49.75 8.496-10.77c48.164-60.98 33.594-162.79-31.57-240.09l-8.496 10.766c-48.164 60.996-33.606 162.79 31.57 240.09m-160.39-92.34 20.168-24.41c60.593-73.34 55.242-182.01-10.051-261.17l-20.176 24.414c-60.586 73.348-55.234 182.03 10.059 261.17m-162.12-111.04 50.274-59.414c61.347-72.5 56.797-181.88-10.363-249.03l-3.934-3.925-32.57 38.488c-66.668 78.789-66.766 194.85-3.407 273.88m-140.4-140.4 31.738-37.527c66.672-78.781 66.778-194.85 3.41-273.88l-31.738 37.5c-66.66 78.801-66.769 194.88-3.41 273.91m-166.52-619.64c-7.899-11.059-24.579-13.95-35.762-5.969-11.492 8.211-14.168 24.238-5.957 35.738 90.519 126.72 180.12 222.58 209.31 252.86l17.364-20.5c0.371-0.429 0.82-0.777 1.218-1.168 0.43-0.441 0.801-0.929 1.282-1.339l16.074-13.602c-29.152-30.379-116.6-124.33-203.53-246.02m271.07 244.61-37.508 31.742c79.012 63.336 195.1 63.258 273.88-3.422l37.52-31.75c-79.032-63.34-195.09-63.23-273.89 3.43"></path><path d="m856.64 1114.8c3.632-2.44 7.761-3.62 11.843-3.62 6.856 0 13.575 3.3 17.688 9.41 35.496 52.82 123.57 133.84 240.31 195.79 10.39 5.51 14.33 18.39 8.84 28.77-5.53 10.38-18.4 14.33-28.77 8.82-108.4-57.51-208.76-139.82-255.71-209.64-6.551-9.76-3.965-22.97 5.793-29.53"></path><path d="m1065.3 941.43c-9.75-6.551-12.35-19.778-5.8-29.524 4.12-6.109 10.83-9.402 17.69-9.402 4.07 0 8.2 1.172 11.85 3.613 69.84 46.942 152.12 147.31 209.62 255.7 5.51 10.38 1.57 23.26-8.81 28.76-10.41 5.53-23.27 1.57-28.77-8.82-61.95-116.74-142.96-204.82-195.78-240.33"></path><path d="m1100.8 1161.4c4.16-4.16 9.59-6.23 15.03-6.23s10.89 2.07 15.04 6.23l100.3 100.29c8.3 8.3 8.3 21.77 0 30.08-8.31 8.31-21.78 8.31-30.09 0l-100.28-100.29c-8.32-8.3-8.32-21.77 0-30.08"></path><path d="m1307.2 213.17c-1.64 1.5-21.03 19-51.85 37.137 23.74 100.64-25.69 198.07-27.87 202.28-2.71 5.254-7.51 9.136-13.2 10.711-5.69 1.621-11.82 0.703-16.85-2.403-4.15-2.55-101.84-63.781-130.47-167.26-0.67-2.403-0.8-4.782-0.65-7.121-21.93-4.711-42.24-11.981-60.26-20.301 13.81 31.332 19.22 55.511 19.68 57.64 1.23 5.801-0.02 11.871-3.45 16.723-3.44 4.84-8.73 8.047-14.62 8.809-4.71 0.597-116.32 14.308-202.04-46.36-85.731-60.672-109.96-170.48-110.96-175.12-1.219-5.801 0.031-11.859 3.457-16.711 3.429-4.859 8.73-8.039 14.621-8.808 1.504-0.192 14.043-1.743 33.183-1.743 40.528 0 110.66 6.903 168.86 48.09 8.879 6.282 16.933 13.192 24.543 20.352 29.168-22.379 96.31-66.059 176.16-66.059 105.02 0 188.22 75.649 191.72 78.867 4.36 4.024 6.85 9.692 6.85 15.622 0 5.949-2.49 11.609-6.85 15.652m-107.7 196.77c11.16-29.82 26.29-84.48 16.45-139.76-29.1 12.34-63.37 21.851-100.47 21.851-1.41 0-2.78-0.152-4.21-0.179 18.9 55.839 62.34 97.41 88.23 118.09m-309.29-226.45c-48.875-34.59-110.28-40.199-144.93-40.199-0.617 0-1.203 0-1.789 0.012 11.23 32.418 36.984 89.828 86.699 124.99 49.719 35.18 112.42 40.941 146.72 40.18-11.231-32.41-36.992-89.797-86.699-124.98m225.27-37.906c-60.94 0-115.15 32.008-143.03 51.977 27.797 19.961 81.837 51.921 143.03 51.921 60.96 0 115.17-32.031 143.04-52-27.8-19.96-81.83-51.898-143.04-51.898"></path></g></g></g></svg>             </span>
            </div>
                        <div class="elementor-icon-box-content">
                <h3 class="elementor-icon-box-title">
                    <span>COMPANY</span>
                </h3>
                                <p class="elementor-icon-box-description">Ritati quam</p>
                            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-25 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-0c25bdb" data-id="0c25bdb" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4be5a3a elementor-view-default elementor-position-top elementor-vertical-align-top elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon-box" data-id="4be5a3a" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon-box.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-box-wrapper">
                        <div class="elementor-icon-box-icon">
                <span class="elementor-icon elementor-animation-">
                <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" id="Ebene_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 138.5 142.5" xml:space="preserve" sodipodi:docname="Icons_Destillerie.svg" inkscape:version="1.0.2-2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15)"><metadata></metadata><defs id="defs25"></defs>
<g id="g20">
    <defs id="defs11">
        <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="16.5" y="7.5" width="105.5" height="128.1"></rect>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" id="use13"></use>
    </clipPath>
    <path style="color:#000000;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:medium;line-height:normal;font-family:sans-serif;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-position:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-alternates:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;font-variation-settings:normal;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;letter-spacing:normal;word-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;writing-mode:lr-tb;direction:ltr;text-orientation:mixed;dominant-baseline:auto;baseline-shift:baseline;text-anchor:start;white-space:normal;shape-padding:0;shape-margin:0;inline-size:0;clip-rule:nonzero;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;color-interpolation:sRGB;color-interpolation-filters:linearRGB;solid-color:#000000;solid-opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;color-rendering:auto;image-rendering:auto;shape-rendering:auto;text-rendering:auto;enable-background:accumulate;stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;stroke:none;opacity:1" d="m 116.8,115.1 c -0.5,0.4 -1.1,0.6 -1.8,0.5 -8.3,-1 -16.6,-1.7 -24.9,-2.2 0.9,-1.4 1.6,-3 2.2,-4.6 7.7,0.5 15.6,1.3 23.3,2.4 1.1,0.1 1.9,1.1 1.9,2.2 0.1,0.7 -0.2,1.3 -0.7,1.7 m -13.8,16 H 35.5 l -5.2,-11.7 c 7.2,-0.7 14.4,-1.3 21.5,-1.6 4.5,4.6 10.7,7.4 17.5,7.4 6.9,0 13.1,-2.8 17.5,-7.4 7.1,0.3 14.3,0.9 21.5,1.6 z M 23.5,115.6 c -0.7,0.1 -1.3,-0.1 -1.8,-0.5 -0.5,-0.4 -0.7,-1 -0.7,-1.7 0,-1.1 0.8,-2.1 1.9,-2.2 7.7,-1.1 15.5,-1.8 23.3,-2.4 0.6,1.6 1.3,3.2 2.2,4.6 -8.3,0.5 -16.6,1.3 -24.9,2.2 m 25.7,-15 c 0,-11.1 9,-20.1 20.1,-20.1 11.1,0 20.1,9 20.1,20.1 0,11.1 -9,20.1 -20.1,20.1 -11.1,0 -20.1,-9 -20.1,-20.1 M 27.3,86 c 2.8,-4.8 6.6,-10 11.3,-15.2 2.9,-3.3 7,-5.5 11.4,-6.4 1,0.8 2.2,1.2 3.6,1.2 H 85 c 1.3,0 2.6,-0.5 3.6,-1.2 4.4,0.9 8.3,3.3 11.2,6.6 4.9,5.7 8.5,10.3 11.1,14.4 3.6,5.6 4.4,12.8 2.1,19.2 l -0.6,1.6 c -6.3,-0.8 -12.6,-1.4 -18.9,-1.8 0.2,-1.3 0.3,-2.5 0.3,-3.8 0,-13.5 -11,-24.5 -24.5,-24.5 -13.5,0 -24.5,11 -24.5,24.5 0,1.3 0.1,2.6 0.3,3.8 -6.3,0.4 -12.6,1.1 -18.9,1.8 L 25.5,104 c -2,-6 -1.4,-12.5 1.8,-18 M 52.2,55.2 c 0,-0.8 0.6,-1.4 1.4,-1.4 H 85 c 0.8,0 1.4,0.6 1.4,1.4 v 4.6 c 0,0.1 0,0.3 -0.1,0.4 -0.3,0.2 -0.5,0.5 -0.7,0.8 -0.2,0.1 -0.4,0.2 -0.6,0.2 H 53.6 c -0.8,0 -1.4,-0.6 -1.4,-1.4 z M 63.1,23.6 c 0.4,-4.4 1.8,-7.6 4.1,-9.5 2.4,-1.9 6,-2.5 10.6,-1.9 H 78 l 38.1,2.8 v 4.7 L 80.9,21 81.8,16.7 c 0.3,-1.2 -0.5,-2.4 -1.7,-2.6 -1.2,-0.3 -2.4,0.5 -2.6,1.7 l -0.6,3 -3,-3 c -0.9,-0.9 -2.3,-0.9 -3.2,0 -0.9,0.9 -0.9,2.3 0,3.2 l 2.8,2.8 -5.6,0.9 c -1.2,0.2 -2,1.3 -1.9,2.5 0.2,1.2 1.3,2.1 2.5,1.9 L 75.6,26 78,49.4 H 60.5 Z m 53.8,83.4 0.3,-0.7 c 2.8,-7.7 1.8,-16.4 -2.5,-23.2 -2.7,-4.3 -6.4,-9 -11.5,-14.9 -3.3,-3.8 -7.6,-6.4 -12.4,-7.8 0,-0.2 0.1,-0.4 0.1,-0.6 V 55.2 C 90.9,52 88.3,49.3 85,49.3 h -2.5 l -2.4,-23.8 38.3,-1.4 c 1.2,0 2.1,-1 2.1,-2.2 V 13 c 0,-1.2 -0.9,-2.1 -2.1,-2.2 l -40,-3 C 72.5,7 67.8,7.9 64.4,10.6 61.1,13.2 59.1,17.5 58.6,23.2 L 56,49.4 h -2.5 c -3.2,0 -5.9,2.6 -5.9,5.9 v 4.6 c 0,0.2 0,0.4 0.1,0.5 -4.8,1.2 -9.2,3.8 -12.5,7.5 -4.9,5.5 -8.9,10.8 -11.8,15.9 -3.8,6.5 -4.6,14.4 -2.2,21.7 l 0.5,1.5 c -3,0.7 -5.2,3.4 -5.2,6.5 0,1.9 0.8,3.7 2.2,5 1.2,1.1 2.8,1.7 4.5,1.7 H 24 c 0.5,-0.1 1.1,-0.1 1.6,-0.2 l 6.4,14.4 c 0.4,0.8 1.2,1.3 2,1.3 h 70.4 c 0.9,0 1.7,-0.5 2,-1.3 l 6.4,-14.4 c 0.5,0.1 1.1,0.1 1.6,0.2 h 0.8 c 1.6,0 3.2,-0.6 4.5,-1.7 1.4,-1.3 2.2,-3.1 2.2,-5 0.1,-3.2 -2.1,-5.8 -5,-6.5" id="path16"></path>
    <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" d="M69.3,89.5c4.6,0,8.6,2.8,10.3,6.9c-6.8-0.2-13.7-0.2-20.6,0C60.7,92.3,64.6,89.5,69.3,89.5    M69.3,111.8c-6.1,0-11-4.9-11.1-11c7.4-0.2,14.9-0.2,22.3,0C80.3,106.9,75.3,111.8,69.3,111.8 M69.3,116.2c8.6,0,15.6-7,15.6-15.6   S77.9,85,69.3,85c-8.6,0-15.6,7-15.6,15.6S60.7,116.2,69.3,116.2" id="path18"></path>
</g>
</svg>              </span>
            </div>
                        <div class="elementor-icon-box-content">
                <h3 class="elementor-icon-box-title">
                    <span>COMPANY</span>
                </h3>
                                <p class="elementor-icon-box-description">Por mod et rem dus</p>
                            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-25 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-a2f6efc" data-id="a2f6efc" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-cb87fe4 elementor-view-default elementor-position-top elementor-vertical-align-top elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon-box" data-id="cb87fe4" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon-box.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-box-wrapper">
                        <div class="elementor-icon-box-icon">
                <span class="elementor-icon elementor-animation-">
                <svg xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svg2" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 184.7 190" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="g10" transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,190.02667)">
    <g id="g12" transform="scale(0.1)">
        <path id="path14" fill="#040606" d="M976.8,210.3c-3-3.1-7-4.8-11.3-4.8H419.2c-5.9,0-9.7,3.1-11.5,4.9c-1.7,1.8-4.6,5.8-4.2,11.6    c3.5,63.4,13,133.8,28.2,209c0.6,2.9,0.7,5.8,0.3,8.8l-107.2,782.8h51l80.5-630.7c6.9-51.6,51.4-90.5,103.5-90.5h263.7    c52.1,0,96.6,38.9,103.5,90.7l80.5,630.5h51L1026,984.3c-0.7-2.3-1.1-4.7-1.1-7.2c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6l-73.5-536.7    c-0.5-3.3-0.3-6.7,0.5-9.9c17.6-70.8,27.5-140.8,29.3-208.1C981.4,217.4,979.8,213.4,976.8,210.3z M908.7,863.1l-33.7-264.2    c-3.4-25.6-25.5-44.9-51.4-44.9H559.8c-25.8,0-47.9,19.3-51.4,44.8l-33.8,264.4H908.7z M954.6,1222.6L916.5,909l-95.5,6.7H472.5    c-1.5,0-3-0.2-4.5-0.4l-39.2,307.3H954.6z M1006,430.1c-0.6,2.5-1.1,5-1.8,7.6l55.9,408.2c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0l56.1,426.5H282.8    c-3-1.5-5.8-3.5-8-6.1c-5-5.7-7.3-13.3-6.2-20.9L379.2,437c-15.2-76.1-24.7-147.4-28.3-212.1c-1-18.6,5.7-37.1,18.5-50.6    c12.9-13.6,31-21.4,49.7-21.4h546.4c18.6,0,36,7.3,49,20.7c13,13.4,19.9,31,19.4,49.6c-1.6,60.3-9.4,122.6-23,185.6"></path>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>              </span>
            </div>
                        <div class="elementor-icon-box-content">
                <h3 class="elementor-icon-box-title">
                    <span>COMPANY</span>
                </h3>
                                <p class="elementor-icon-box-description">Os iliqui sin rempellit</p>
                            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
```